# Logic App Custom Connector - How to expect client id & secret from end user?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am creating custom connector for Web API having oAuth 2.0 Authentication.
I need to take client id & secret from the End User who will be using the customer Connector.

Example would be like Acumatica Connector, which has clientid & secret as input

I have tried Generic OAuth option in Security Tab, but it asked for client Id & Secret upfront. When using custom connector, it uses same client Id.

Comment: Basically what you need is you need your user to be authenticated before you display the actual parameters of the connector. Is that right ?

Comment: Yeah pretty unclear what you need. could you paste some screenshots / code samples please ?

Comment: @Thomas looks like he needs to access credentials via params, which is bad practise. Credentials should be asked only once and the connection is preserved

Comment: @Th https://ibb.co/YLFBGqF  Here is the screenshot of Acumatica  Connector. I want user to provide client id & secret key for connection with Web API.

Comment: @Thomas , Hope comments make the question clear

Answer (score 0):

So you want two inputs which accepts `clientId` and `clientSecret` to create a API connection. Here's the swagger json which you can use

```
{
    "apiVersion": "[variables('connectorApiVersion')]",
    "name": "[variables('tracking_connectorName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/customApis",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
        "connectionParameters": {
            "ClientId": {
                "type": "securestring",
                "uiDefinition": {
                    "displayName": "ClientId",
                    "description": "Enter ClientId",
                    "tooltip": "Enter ClientId",
                    "constraints": {
                        "tabIndex": 2,
                        "clearText": false,
                        "required": "true"
                    }
                }
            },
            "ClientSecret": {
                "type": "securestring",
                "uiDefinition": {
                    "displayName": "ClientSecret",
                    "description": "Enter ClientSecret",
                    "tooltip": "Enter ClientSecret",
                    "constraints": {
                        "tabIndex": 2,
                        "clearText": false,
                        "required": "true"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "description": "meh nah hyaaah",
        "displayName": "[variables('tracking_connectorName')]",
        "backendService": {
            "serviceUrl": "[concat('https://', parameters('myApiUrl')]"
        },
        "swagger": {
            "swagger": "2.0",
            "info": {
                "title": "Your connector name",
                "description": "Your connector description",
                "version": "1.0.0"
            },
            "host": "[concat(parameters('myApi')]",
            "basePath": "/",
            "schemes": [
                "https",
                "http"
            ],
            "paths": {},
            "definitions": {},
            "securityDefinitions": {
            }
        }
    }
}
```